Django user_auth how to foreign key one to many
What I'm looking for is that a many users can be part of a tenant, so my idea in the beginning was to foreign key from user to tenant but I can't found how to do this. This is what I have at the moment:
models.py
class Tenants(models.Model):
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    sub_dominio = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tenants"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa

But with this solution I can only have a User per Tenant, how can I do Many users per tenant?

I understood that you are connecting multiple users to the tenants model.
The foreign key must be generated by the user in reverse.
tenants/models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Tenants(models.Model):
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    sub_dominio = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tenants"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa

users/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, PermissionsMixin
from tenants.models import Tenants

# Create your models here.


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  
  objects = UserManager()
  
  username = models.CharField(
      max_length=150,
      unique=True,
  ) 
  email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    default=False,
  )
  is_active = models.BooleanField(
    default=True,
  )

  tenants = models.ForeignKey(Tenants, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='users')
  
  EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
  USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.username


Thanks for the response, so in order to connect the user in reverse the only way is to use the AbstractUser and not with the built in?

As far as I know, yes.

Strictly speaking, you can add a ForeignKey from the user model to the Tenant, even if that model exists, just by performing the logic that Django itself uses:
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Tenant(models.Model):
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    sub_dominio = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tenants'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa


user = get_user_model()

models.ForeignKey(
    Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
).contribute_to_class(User, 'tenant')
at the bottom, we thus add a field named tenant to the User model. But I don't think it is a good idea to do that. If you need to update the user model, usually you make a custom one.


Note: Normally a Django model is given a singular name [django-antipatterns], so Tenant instead of Tenants.


Thanks for your response, what I have read is that ideally you create a custom user model at the beginning of the project and it is not my case, also that if you are already in the midle of the project it is difficult but not impossible to do it.  My workaround at the moment was to create a user profile and use a foreing key to link it with the tenants table. Let me know if you have a better approach. Thanks!

@JorgeLópez: normally it is not undoable to mix one in later. Especially if you eferred to the user through settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. A profile is often the second approach used. But the disadvantage of that is that now a third model is used (User, UserProfile and Tenant) making "juggling" with these models more cumbersome.
